# Is there a python package for Multivariate Newton Raphson Solver

Tags: python, numerical-methods

I have a set of multivariate polynomial equations to solve and I am looking for a package that can help me get an approximate solutions (we can input the number of iterations etc as parameter). Is there a package that helps solve these.

P.S. the number of equations can get rather large so the package must be scalable and tested. For example: A Newton Raphson Implementation.

Comment: Note that finding solutions of multivariate polynomial systems of higher dimension and degree is exceedingly difficult to hopeless. Especially if you want to find real solutions. One would need a starting point/initial guess close to a solution, with the closeness becoming more strict the higher the Bezout number (=product of all total degrees). (Semi-)numerical path-following/homotopy methods exist and are more economic than the purely algebraic Gröbner methods, but still not really fast.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thank you for this extremely helpful comment. Let us assume the solution can have only 2 known possible integer values for each variable in any valid solution (say 0 or 1) or (1 or -1). Would that problem be still difficult?

Comment: and one more Q: How do we define/measure 'closeness' or 'distance'? for a single variable its easy. But how do we measure it for multivariate system of equations (assume an initial guess is given and we know one of the solutions).

Comment: There are some estimates for the region of quadratic convergence (Smale's alpha-beta-gamma theory). There is some literature that starting somewhere around dimension 7 (I think) the set of good starting points for the Newton iteration becomes very thin. /// A system of quadratic equations still has Bezout number `2^n` (polyhedral methods can reduce this bound by some of the solutions at projective infinity). In my experience, starting from Bezout numbers around 150 the solution process slows down to a crawl. Using floating point numbers the precision bits might be used up at Bezout number 50.

Answer (score 0):

scipy

Example

scipy.optimize.newton(func, x0, fprime=None, args=(), tol=1.48e-08, maxiter=50, fprime2=None, x1=None, rtol=0.0, full_output=False, disp=True)

Comment: can you provide a complete multivariate example for a set of equations?